# c++ - Execute a binary file from memory

Tags: c++

Hello Guys I really need help in my c/c++ programming skills. I have to load a binary file, maybe a simple "hello World" and execute it directly from a buffer. Therefore I loaded my buffer with the binary file and tried to set the programming pointer to the buffer. But it doesn't work correctly. Could you please help me with useful suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  FILE *fileptr;
  char *buffer;
  long filelen;

  fileptr = fopen("helloworld", "rb"); //Open File in binary mode
  fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END); //Jump to the end of file
  filelen = ftell(fileptr);  //Get the current byte offset in File
  rewind(fileptr); // Jump back to beginnig of the file

  buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char));
  fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr);
  fclose(fileptr);

  int *ret;
  ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
  (*ret) = (int)*buffer;
}
```

Comment: `ret = (int *)&ret + 2; (*ret) = (int)*buffer`..what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Depending on your platform the memory buffer may not have its execute permissions bit set.  This is outside the C++ standard and you will need to use OS specific APIs

Comment: There is no language C/C++! This looks like pure C, but as you explicitly state C++, I assume that's what you mean.

Comment: Does the pointer point directly to the start of the `.code` section (is it ELF?) ? Also, make sure your binary file does not contain relocations or uses dynamic libraries in a way that prevents it from running directly like this.

Comment: There is much more to loading a "binary". And the program code is not just  stored as "binary" you can simply load/run. Do more research on executable file formats, modern OS loaders, virtual memory/memory protection, section, and much more. That all you'll need to manually load code (if possible at all without special OS functions).

Comment: Most operating systems will disallow execution of data as part of their virus protection.

Comment: yeah it is pure c but it doesn't matter at this point. The helloWorld executable is for example only a gcc "compiled printf 'hello World!'" program, you know what I mean.

@Olaf I read something about what to do to load a binary, but why it is so complicated? A normal script kiddie binary binder do nothing more than change the pointers to the right sections, in my opinion!?

Comment: `exec()` isn't complicated.

Comment: No, it is C++. If you compile as C, edit your question. So ask a script-kiddie **how** it works! They are called like that because they don't know that, but use ready-made scripts.

Comment: don't piss me off, plz. According to your profile, you should really know how does it work and that it is c and not the incrementation...

Comment: Some time ago, I've wrote a blog post about running a foreign code from memory: https://itachi.pl/uruchamianie-kodu-w-pamieci-programu/

Unfortunately, it is written in polish, and I'm aware that Google Translate isn't good enough to translate it wisely. I will translate it in the evening and post as an answer. By this time, look at it, maybe something will lighten your path. It is not easy, yet still juicy and worth knowing.

Comment: "yeah it is pure c": if so (which I believe it is), then retag [tag:C]. You don't seem to get the point of how things work here: it's about having a large set of Q&A, and that implies correct tagging.

Comment: It is Stackoverflow. Everybody who's programming should know Stackoverflow. It is the top most searched Site on Google for programming questions, I think.. but I didn't proof it. Therefore it is already tagget under c/c++. I compiled it with g++ so it is a c++ program and has the correct header with the correct tags. And one reason why there are answers and comments is, because in so much forums exists so much flamer ;). Have I forgot something?

Comment: I know this is nitpicking (but programmers need to be rigorous), but when you say "..has the correct header...", well no, C++ headers have no extension, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header). And about your question, I think this is not possible when the target has an OS. Could be possible on a dedicated target running custom code (but having a compiler available). But you'd get better help by providing a use case.

Answer (score 0):

The program instructions are placed in the read only region of the process memory called text code segment and it is decided when the exe is generated by the compiler. The OS  simply won't expect program instructions in the stack or the heap! Otherwise viruses would have been very easy to made....

Comment: Okay yes, I'm familiar with the theoretical concept. But there should be possible ways maybe with buffer overflows or something like that. As I already mentioned there are practical examples and I try to understand how does it work.